# Limit for the flagged items in Circuit REST API

Tags: circuit-sdk

I see that there is no pagination in most of the Circuit API.

One example is: GET/conversations/{convId}/messages/flag

Does that mean that I will always get all the messages at once? Is there any plans to add pagination to the UPIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the endpoints do offer pagination but in the way that you have to specify a timestamp and a number of items to retrieve. For example GET /conversations or GET /conversations/{convId}/items can be paged in that way.

For the flagged items pagination support is currently not available due to the fact that the backend offers all available flagged items at once. We know that this is not very optimal atm and we are planning to fix such issue in a new version 3 in the future, but that may take some time until the release.